# Python numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

Does anyone know, how I could skip the parenthesis from a text file I trying to read using `numpy.genfromtxt`
My data file is of the format

```
1.466 ((5.68 3.3 45.7)(4.5 6.7 9.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.genfromtxt can accept iterators:

```
import numpy as np
import re

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    lines = (line.replace('(',' ').replace(')',' ') for line in f)
    arr = np.genfromtxt(lines)
print(arr)
```

yields

```
[  1.466   5.68    3.3    45.7     4.5     6.7     9.5  ]
```

---

Alternatively, you could use (in Python2) the `str.translate` or (in Python3) the `bytes.translate` method, which is a bit faster:

```
import numpy as np
import re

try:
    # Python2
    import string
    table = string.maketrans('()','  ')
except AttributeError:
    # Python3
    table = bytes.maketrans(b'()',b'  ')

with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    lines = (line.translate(table) for line in f)
    arr = np.genfromtxt(lines)
print(arr)
```